# Cauchy problem of 2D euler equation

Tags: numerical-methods, fluid-dynamics

In my course, i need to research about how to solve Cauchy problem of 2D euler equation. But i didn't any find any article show how to find approximate solution of this problem. Can someone suggest me a document?